# Classic Asp page in Asp.net Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've tried for a week now to use a Classic Asp app inside my Asp.net Core app. Some part of our Classic Asp app will be converted later to the new framework but for now I have to make those pages work inside my .Net Core app.

I've tried a couple of things but the only thing that seems to work is to create additionnal app on different sub-domain.

Images, JS files and HTML files works great inside my app, but not Classic Asp pages.

I've created a simple test application to verify everything and here's what it looks like :

[image]

In that example, /wwwroot/index.asp and /test.asp throw a 404 error but all the other pages (/wwwroot/htmlpage.html and /Project_Readme.html) works just fine.

Do you guys have any idea what I should do to make this work ?

Comment: I have a few additional questions…
1) by Classic asp pages do you mean the technology that existing way back in 1996-1997 ? 
2) Considering webforms is not even supported with asp.net core, what makes you think classic asp (which is older) will work with asp.net core? Did you find an example somewhere? An article? I’m asking because I’m curious as to what made you think this was possible (unless, I’m the one who doesn’t grasp what you’re trying to do).

Comment: Yeah I mean the old stuff. I thought it would work because in both case the application pool on IIS needs to be on "No Managed Code". It might not be possible but I thought since it is possible to run a Classic Asp page in a site folder on IIS it might have been something in the Asp.Net Core pipeline that is blocking it.

Comment: Do you have Classic ASP enabled in IIS?  From IIS7 and upwards it's disabled by default, and if you ask IIS for a file with an unregistered extension you'll get a 404 error.  If it is enabled then there should be no problem viewing a standalone classic asp page. ASP.net core is designed to be cross platform.  Obviously classic asp is not - it needs IIS

Comment: Yes it is enabled. We use this server for a couple of app in Classic ASP and some .Net stuff too. I just verified on our server and it seems that the mime type for .asp file was not in the MIME types list. I added it as a application/asp and as a text/asp but it didn't change anything.